# How to find splitted archive in java?

Tags: java, zip, archive

In java i need to find the given archive is splitted archive or not. I need for all archive formates like zip,rar,tar,tar.gz,tar.Z.

[Zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/) is used to identify only the splitted zip. For other format archive i need API.

Please help me .

Comment: I would try decoding them and if you can they are not split. If you can't read them, then they are split or corrupt or a different format.

Comment: Doesnt Apache Commons Compress handle multi-volume archives?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey For me no need to read that file. Just i need to know whether it is splitted archive or not. Thats enough.

Comment: @Santhoshkumar There is no way to know without reading the contents. You could make assumptions based on the filename, but that is just guessing IMHO.

Comment: @biziclop Apache Commons Compress handle multi-volume archives. In that API no option to find the given archive is splitted or not.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey  I think reading headers is enough for to find splitted or not. For that only i am looking for a java API.

Comment: The header of the first file will be correct and the same whether it is split or not. Reading additional files might tell you the file is split. I would use the API you mentioned and if it fails it might be split, truncated or corrupt.

Comment: I need to show the exact status of the file whether it is splitted or corrupted like that.Also i have only one part of that file , so without other files i need to identify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the splitted Rar file i find an API.

More details
https://github.com/edmund-wagner/junrar

This  project have options to find splitted and encrypted rar archive.

But for other archive formats still searching.